# Redshift (copy data between two columns of different data types

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, talend

can we copy the data between two columns of different types in existing redshift table.?

Comment: The short answer is:  yes.  If you provide some more detail (what types of data, what are some example values, what do you hope to have for results), someone can try to guide you.

Comment: Ok, so I am having emp_id as identity column in mysql and i want to move that data to redshift and there on the new data is loaded directly to redshift.     But, when I create a table identity column and tried to move data, I am getting error.